# Count number of Set bits in a long number

Tags: java, bit

I need to count number of set bits in a long number. Also I need to optimize the same.
I'm using the following code:

```
public static int countSetBits(long number) {
    int count = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        ++count;
        number &= number - 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Any modifications would be appreciated.

Comment: You only want to count the '1' in your `long` am I right?

Comment: Yes. So if the input is 2 the o/p should be 1. For 3 it should be 2.

Comment: What's wrong with [Long.bitCount]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#bitCount(long))

Comment: Long.bitCount is likely to be optimized better than anything you could write, possibly even using intrinsics to turn it into one CPU instruction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write it without subtraction as follow

```
public static int countSetBits(long number) {
    int count = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        count += number&1L;
        number>>=1L;
    }
    return count;
}
```

If You want to use Java's built-in libraries then can use [bitCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#bitCount%28long%29)

```
Long.bitCount(number)
```

And if you want to see [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#Long.bitCount%28long%29) then

```
public static int  bitCount(long i) {
   i = i - ((i >>> 1) & 0x5555555555555555L);
   i = (i & 0x3333333333333333L) + ((i >>> 2) & 0x3333333333333333L);
   i = (i + (i >>> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL;
   i = i + (i >>> 8);
   i = i + (i >>> 16);
   i = i + (i >>> 32);
   return (int)i & 0x7f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something likewise,

```
public static int countSetBits(long n){
        int count = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 64 ; i++){ // 64-bit for long data-type
            temp = 1;
            temp = temp << i;
            temp = n & temp;
            if((temp > 0))
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: This approach fails. See [this question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59991296/counting-number-of-set-bits-in-a-long-number/59992079#59992079).