# Counting number of set bits in a long number

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116205/count-number-of-set-bits-in-a-long-number).

My query is, following approach-1 works, however the variation of it, that is approach-2 does not, rather it gives double the value of expected output. I can not find out why.

**Approach-1**

```
public class Solution {
    public int numSetBits(long a) {
        int count = 0;
        long temp = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 64 ; i++) { // 64-bit for long data-type
            temp = 1;
            temp = temp << i;
            temp = a & temp;
            if((temp > 0))
                count++;
        }
      return count;
    }
}
```

**Approach-2**

```
public class Solution {
    public int numSetBits(long a) {
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<64; i++) {
            if((a & (1 << i))>0) count++;
        }
      return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second approach fails because the result of `1 << i` is an `int`, not a `long`. So the bit mask wraps around, and so the lower 32 bits of `a` get scanned twice, while the higher 32 bits of `a` are left uncounted.

So, when `i` reaches the value 32, `(1 << i)` will not be 2<sup>32</sup>, but 2<sup>0</sup> (i.e. 1), which is the same as when `i` was 0. Similarly when `i` is 33, `(1 << i)` will not be 2<sup>33</sup>, but 2<sup>1</sup>, ...etc.

Correct this by making the constant 1 a `long`:

```
(1L << i)
```

Comment: If you can please explain in little details as well, Specially the part: `bit mask wraps around, and so the lower 32 bits of a get scanned twice, while the higher 32 bits of a are left uncounted`

Comment: I added more text to illustrate what happens.